# Lazyload background-image with lazysizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-lazyload

I want to load a background-image "lazy" with the library http://afarkas.github.io/lazysizes/
They do mention that the loading of "anything" lazily is possible. But the whole documentation on that is that one:

```
<div data-ride="carousel" data-script="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" class="carousel lazyload">
    <!-- widget content -->
<div>
```

And I don't get how I could use that for a background-image. Does anybody have experience there on that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To load a background image using lazysizes use the `data-bg` attribute

```
import "lazysizes/plugins/unveilhooks/ls.unveilhooks";
```

Usage example:

```
<div class="lazyload" data-bg="/path/to/image.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: You'll need the unveilhooks plugin for this to work: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/tree/e305d28d4b6c4ff9f12dd4d438d5d7c5d41574db/plugins/unveilhooks

Comment: Is it possible to lazyload a webp and a jpeg as a fallback for using as background-image of a div?

Answer (score 13):

If you want to load background image using lazyload just you need to add one small block of code (No need to add any plugin) -

```
//add simple support for background images:
document.addEventListener('lazybeforeunveil', function(e){
    var bg = e.target.getAttribute('data-bg');
    if(bg){
        e.target.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + bg + ')';
    }
});
```

Comment: @DeepSojitra do you have LazySizes installed? This solution works fine for me.

Answer (score 4):

Probably someone may find this useful. In my case, using the same library - "lazysizes" I had to change **data-bg** for **data-bgset**:

```
<div class="lazyload" data-bgset=""></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to load an image as background, follow this [doc](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/tree/gh-pages/plugins/bgset).
This is a plugin of lazysizes

Answer (score 1):

As mention before you need to add some plugin to do that.
This is the configuration that i use to all my project.

Required lazysizes plugin:

- [respimg polyfill](https://github.com/aFarkas/wp-lazysizes/tree/master/js/lazysizes/plugins/respimg) (only needed in browser that don't support respimg)
- [bgset](https://github.com/aFarkas/wp-lazysizes/tree/master/js/lazysizes/plugins/bgset) this is the core plugin

than you can set your custom breakpoint in this way

```
window.lazySizesConfig = window.lazySizesConfig || {};
window.lazySizesConfig.customMedia = {
    '--small'   : '(max-width: 576px)',
    '--medium'  : '(max-width: 768px)'
};
```

And here the markup

```
<div class="lazyload" data-bgset="URL-OF-SMALL-IMAGE[--small] URL-OF-MEDIUM-IMAGE[--medium] | URL-OF-FULL-SIZE-IMAGE", data-sizes="auto")
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify the version of the Lazyload.

The version to work this:

```
<div class="lazy" data-bg="/path/to/image.jpg"></div>
```

is:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vanilla-lazyload@17.6.1/dist/lazyload.min.js"></script>
```

ps: do not forget insert the call

```
var lazyLoadInstance = new LazyLoad({
  elements_selector: ".lazy",
  load_delay: 100,
  effect : "fadeIn"
  // ... more custom settings?
  });
```

Comment: You need to correct elements_selector: ".lazy" to elements_selector: ".lazyload"